# How to compare if two tables are the same with Office-js

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I'm iterating through the whole document, paragraph by paragraph. When a paragraph is in a table I want to store it in an array. But I don't want to store duplicates.

I tried to simply use `indexOf`, with `==` or with `===` but without success:

```js
let tables = [];

// Iterate over the document
for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.items.length; ++i) 
{
  // if this is in a table
  if (paragraphs.items[i].tableNestingLevel > 0)
  {
    let table = paragraphs.items[i].parentTable;
    table.load();
    await context.sync();
    
    // Try to avoid duplicates in the array (doesn't work)
    if(tables.indexOf(table) == -1)
    {
        tables.push(table);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

I know that `document.body.tables` exists, but I iterate over paragraphs to parse other structures than tables in the order they are in the document.

Comment: You need to say much more than "doesn't work". What do you expect to see and what do you actually see?

Comment: Fair point ! What I see is duplicate tables in my `tables` array. Despite making a check before hand with === or == or indexOf to see it the table was already added to the list.